No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed..How Can i solve this problem during deployement in vercel
enter image description here
please gelp me to deploy in vercel;
Ihad tried in vercel for deployemeny but it is showing build folder not found
How Can i solve this problem during deployement in vercel.
all my project file structure and deployement configuraion attacjed above
